# Error on using Oracle instant connect on osx with perl?

Tags: macos, oracle, perl

I am trying to connect to an `Oracle` database from perl using Oracle instant connect.

The error message is:

```
install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't locate DBD/Oracle.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 
/Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4 
/System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .)
```

How can I fix this?

cpan DBD::Oracle  also had some problems:

```
CPAN.pm: Going to build P/PY/PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.68.tar.gz

Multiple copies of Driver.xst found in: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/ /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/ at Makefile.PL line 39
Using DBI 1.631 (for perl 5.012004 on darwin-thread-multi-2level) installed in /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/

Configuring DBD::Oracle for perl 5.012004 on darwin (darwin-thread-multi-2level)

Remember to actually *READ* the README file! Especially if you have any problems.

Trying to find an ORACLE_HOME
Found /Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2 /Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2 /Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2 /Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2 /Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2 /Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2

 WARNING: Setting ORACLE_HOME env var to /Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2 for you.
 WARNING: If these tests fail you may have to set ORACLE_HOME yourself!
 Installing on a darwin, Ver#12.0
 Using Oracle in /Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2
 dyld: Library not loaded: /ade/b/3572816174/oracle/sqlplus/lib/libsqlplus.dylib
 Referenced from: /Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2/sqlplus
 Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/lib/libsqlplus.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture

    If sqlplus failed due to a linker/symbol/relocation/library error or similar problem
    then it's likely that you've not configured your environment correctly.
    Specifically, your DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable
    set to include the directory containing the Oracle libraries.

 I'm having trouble finding your Oracle version number... trying harder

 WARNING: I could not determine Oracle client version so I'll just
 default to version 8.0.0.0. Some features of DBD::Oracle may not work.
 Oracle version based logic in Makefile.PL may produce erroneous results.
 You can use "perl Makefile.PL -V X.Y.Z" to specify a your client version.

 Oracle version 8.0.0.0 (8.0)
 DBD::Oracle no longer supports Oracle client versions before 9.2 
 Try a version before 1.25 for 9 and 1.18 for 8! at Makefile.PL line 271.
 Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
 PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.68.tar.gz
 /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
 Running make test
 Make had some problems, won't test
 Running make install
 Make had some problems, won't install
```

Comment: I'm afraid that if he has just the instant client, nothing else, he'll probably miss some of the stuff needed to compile DBD::Oracle. The answer remains valid though: in addition to the Oracle client, you need to install the perl module for Oracle access (DBD::Oracle), which normally means you need a full client and a compiler on your machine.

Comment: Thanks. cpan DBD::Oracle returns some errors:

Comment: That indented paragraph & the 4 lines above it catch my eye.  Are you sure you've got the right version of the instant client for your machine?  The folks at Apple have recently changed which version of the C libraries they use, thus you need to be careful that you've got the right library versions for anything new you want to compile.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that installing the perl library via CPAN is not currently supported in El Capitan because of the security changes to DYLD* variables.

You'll have to manually compile the module and do some workarounds, here is a step by step instruction.

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1152806